# Rename duplicate property entries in a List of Objects

Tags: vb.net, list, duplicates, rename

I have a List of Objects where each object contains a String Property. These String Property has to be unique so I tried add an ascending number to the duplicated. First off I thought [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51004408/c-rename-replace-duplicates-in-list-with-an-added-number) could help me but it is for Lists not Lists of objects and all attemps to translate the code to vb were not successfull so I tried another way.

```
Object1.String = "Test"
Object2.String = "Test"
```

should be transformed to

```
Object1.String = "Test"
Object2.String = "Test1"
```

This is what I have tried:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim obj1 As New TestCls
        Dim obj2 As New TestCls
        Dim obj3 As New TestCls

        obj1.p1 = "Test"
        obj2.p1 = "Test1"
        obj3.p1 = "Test"

        Dim lstmp As New List(Of TestCls)
        lstmp.Add(obj1)
        lstmp.Add(obj2)
        lstmp.Add(obj3)

        For Each elementA As TestCls In lstmp
            For Each elementB As TestCls In lstmp
                If elementA.p1 = elementB.p1 Then
                    elementB.p1 = elementB.p1 & 1
                End If
            Next
        Next
        Dim i As Integer = 0
    End Sub
End Module

Class TestCls
    Public Property p1 As String
End Class
```

But the result is Test1 and Test111 and even more confusing with a lot of objects. Anyone who can help me here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to increment it instead of always concatenating 1. I would use a dictionary to count the occurences of each `p1`. This prevents also the bug that you generate existing `p1`s:

```
Dim p1Counter = New Dictionary(Of String, Int32)

For Each obj In lstmp
    Dim p1Count As Int32
    Dim containsP1 = p1Counter.TryGetValue(obj.p1, p1Count)
    If containsP1 Then
        p1Count += 1
        Dim newP1 = obj.p1 & p1Count
        While p1Counter.ContainsKey(newP1)
            p1Count += 1
            newP1 = obj.p1 & p1Count
        End While
        obj.p1 = newP1
    Else
        p1Count = 1
    End If
    p1Counter(obj.p1) = p1Count
Next
```